# ElasticSearch Facet Count Does Not Match Total Items

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, nest

I have 98 documents in my search index. When I do a facet search with no filter, the facet count does not match the number of items in the index for that term. If I set the facet set equal to the current number of documents, 98, the facet count is returned with the correct number of items for that term. Below is the json for the facet search.

Does Not Return the correct number of items

```
{
  "facets": {
    "brand": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand",
        "all_terms": true
      }
    },
    "global": true
  }
}
```

Does return the correct number of items

```
{
  "facets": {
    "brand": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand",
        "all_terms": true,
        "size": 98
      }
    },
    "global": true
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known unresolved issue. See issue [#1832](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1832) for more details.

Comment: This indeed appears to be a bug I'm seeing. I changed the number of shards for that index to 1 and it start providing the correct count totals. Thanks.